# Finding subgroups of the prime decomposition of a group

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let G be the group of invertible elements in the ring $\mathbb{Z}_{36}$.
Find the subgroups of the prime decomposition of G.

Work:

Well, the invertible elements in $\mathbb{Z}_{36}$ are:

{ 1,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,25,31,35 } the set of all elements in $\mathbb{Z}_{36}$ which relatively prime to 36 (so even numbers and multiples of 3)

So, G={ 1,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,25,31,35 }. 
Now my task is to find the subgroups of G's primary decomposition.

This is where I run into problems. I can see that the primary decomposition of something like $\mathbb{Z}_{60}$ will have the form: G[2] x G[3] x G[5], but im sort of stuck because my group G doesn't seem to have the same structure as a group like $\mathbb{Z}_{60}$.

Comment: Your $G$ has $11$ elements (i.e. prime order) but that is wrong, because $\phi(36)=12.$ You missed $\gcd(29,36)=1$.

Comment: Sorry. Typo. I firgured it out, thanks though!